# Google maps tile ground overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm implementing a ground overlay that covers the entire world map. I have 2 issues at the moment.

First the image even if it's proportioned for the entire world map and I have stretched it (I think) properly, still displays somewhat weirdly stretched.

Second I'd like to tile the ground overlay to 'cover more worlds' when zoomed out excessively, but don't know if tiling is possible.

here's my code:

```
var start = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    sw = new google.maps.LatLng(-84, -178), // South West
    ne = new google.maps.LatLng(84, 178), // North East

    imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne),

    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: start,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions),

     oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("images/world.png", imageBounds);

     oldmap.setMap(map);
```

You can see it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maurizioliberato/A64nb/1/embedded/result/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you concern about projection when you stitch the images? Google Maps API uses Mercator Projection.
So I recommend you use a stitcher software to make a map image; PTGui, Hugin, etc.

Comment: not really I'm pretty new to Google maps, don't know what projection is. Could you provide some links to the software you mentioned please? :)

Comment: I use PTGui, it's not free software, but Hugin is also famous and free software. When you generate the stitched image, you can choose projection. So you will choose "Mercator Projection". (PTGui, trial) http://www.ptgui.com/ (Hugin, free)http://hugin.sourceforge.net/